# Git merging is not working

Tags: git, github

I'm a amateur git user.My client setup a project repository on git and a branch is created for me using which I always push my updates and send pull request to my client who take the responsibility of merging my changes to the master branch. Now i have to merge my changes on a different branch named `PQR`(suppose). My branch is `XYZ`(suppose). Now I need idea on how to do that.Whenever I tried to pull `PQR` branch's code in my local it displaying permission denied error.From my local I can checkout with brunch `PQR` but that does not fulfill my requirements.

Comment: Are u sure that branch `PQR` is a remote branch? I mean if you `git fetch origin` will there be a `origin/PQR` in your repo?

Comment: I used "git branch -a" and PQR is being displayed as remote branch

Comment: `git log --oneline --decorate`, what does that output?

Comment: It displaying the merging histories

Comment: Actually I'm expecting you see something like `<sha1> (HEAD, origin/PQR, PQR) your comments`